# Indexing table with a lot of columns and has varying Where clauses SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, columnstore

My question is pretty general: If a table has (what I believe to be) a lot of columns (60+) and has dynamic queries executed against it, is a columnstore index a good route to go? What are other indexing techniques one could use if the predicate of the where clause could be like something like

```
WHERE (Column_i = val1 or Column_i = val2) and Column_j = val3
```

but the next query could be

```
WHERE Column_p < val4 and Column_n = val5
```

? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You could consider creating multiple indices to cover the various queries.  Which indices you choose, and whether SQL Server would choose to use them, would depend on the actual queries and select clauses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so monitor which queries users are executing most and index based off of those primarily with some more general indexes for the less likely queries? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Columnstore is really best used for high analytical workloads, where you're aggregating a ton of rows(think millions/billions).It doesn't do so great in heavy OLTP transactional systems. It's improved leaps and bounds in that arena since it's inception in 2012, but it still is much more costly to write/update Columnstore than rowstore.